# RoR - Validate string on website, no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails app I have build a function to validate if a piece of javascript is added to a certain website. When I run this code I don't get any errors in my log, but my app says:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

But when I check the logs I don't see any errors. The code I have used is the following:

```
def validate_installation
  data  = HTTParty.get(self.website)
  url = "http://www.smartnotif.com/sn.js"
  if data.body.include? url
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

When I run this code on my local development machine it runs fine, but when I try to runs this production machine on DigitalOcean I have this problem with the same code, no errors.

Comment: Can you also add the part of your code, which uses this method?

Comment: Though this is not answer to your question as per the ruby standards you can replace `if-else-end` with just `data.body.include? url`

Comment: @slowjack2k this part is defined in a model, I use this code in a controller like this project.validate_installation

Comment: @Salil thank you for the tip!

Comment: Maybe you run into an exception. You can catch it via `rescue => e; Rails.logger.error "Error : #{e}"`  at the end of your method.

Comment: When there is a 500 server error and the *We're sorry, but something went wrong* message is shown on a website then Rails logs the error and a stack trace into the servers log file. What is the exact error message? Please post the error message with the stack trace.

Comment: @spickermann this problem only occurs when I run this code on my production machine on DigitalOcean. It doesn't generate an error, that's the whole problem. Other errors are shown just fine, but it seems more like a timeout problem or something.

Comment: It's a virtual machine so yes I have acces, but as I told before I can see the activity in the log, but there aren't any errors generated when I go to the page with that uses this method.

Comment: When there is no error in the application log, is there an error in the web server's log (unicorn, puma, apache, or whatever you use)?

Comment: @spickermann yes, thanks, found an error in the nginx logs:    upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Answer (score 1):

Try to include

```
require 'httparty'
```

Restart rails server

```
rails s
```

Also check the permission of log folder, why it is not writing error in log folder
Also try: Use self keyword as you are calling it as class method

```
def self.validate_installation
  data  = HTTParty.get(self.website)
  url = "http://www.smartnotif.com/sn.js"
  if data.body.include? url
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: I have added require and restarted the server, no luck. The log files work fine, other info and errors are logged correctly

Comment: @PieterB I have updated the answer. I think you need to make class method as you are calling it as project.validate_installation  Just add self with method name